# How to store multi byte characters in SQL Server database using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, unicode, codeigniter-2

I'm using MS SQL Server and CodeIgniter 2 with Active Record for a project I'm working on, and I just stumbled upon this issue:

When I submit a form that contains Chinese or Hindi characters, I store it in a table, and when I view it all I get are question marks. If I try English or Greek characters, everything seems to work fine.

The reason I believe this is something to do with the PHP I'm writing, is because if I copy-paste the chinese text directly in SQL Server Management Studio, all values are stored and displayed perfectly, both on the SQL Studio, and the web application.

These are the db settings I'm using:

```
$db['local']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['local']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['local']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['local']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['local']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['local']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['local']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['local']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['local']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['local']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['local']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

This is the structure of the table I'm testing on right now:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[languages](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [language] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [language_local] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [lang_code] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [core] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_languages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,         ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

And this is my charset encoding in config.php

```
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
```

**New troubleshooting data**

I tried to save the following string through my form: Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn

CodeIgniter replied with this error:

```
An error occurred translating the query string to UTF-16: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page. .
```

This doesn't appear when I try to store Chinese characters
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Perhaps setting it in your PHP INI file will help you troubleshoot? ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');

Comment: Also on your webpages verify you are using the correct encoding. <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: I wasn't aware of this setting in php! I'll check it tommorow and inform :)

Comment: It wasn't the setting... Also all my pages have the <meta> charset to UTF-8 :/

Comment: You are using a class from CodeIgniter or some other API to interface with your db? Write a quick and mysqli connector and pass an SQL insert statement with the UTF-8 characters in the body of the form, to see if you can track it down to an issue with the API you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Looks like this answer is getting a lot of attention, and I feel bad for not posting the actual solution to my problem... I'd guess it's bad etiquette to de-select an answer I selected many years ago so I won't for now. Here goes...</s>

No changes needed to be done to the settings. The problem is query related, and unfortunately CodeIgniter doesn't support the proper query format out of the box.

So when you want to insert multibyte characters into your table, you have to prepend the character `N` before your string.

So in my example above the query should look like this in order to work

```
INSERT INTO test_table (title) VALUES (N'Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn')
```

No, CI doesn't currently give you a built in way to do this. It is planed to be added in on CI4, but until then [here is a hack for you](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/1602)

Answer (score 9):

Try to convert your input with iconv() before insert to db :

```
$input = iconv('','UTF-8',$str);
```

Comment: this is bad practice. if you have setup everything correctly (database-interface, encoding of your files), then you NEVER EVER need `iconv()` or any other encoding-converting function in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Handling encoding in Microsoft's SQL Server from PHP can be quite painful. The CharacterSet-option was included with version 1.1 of Microsoft SQL Server Driver for PHP (SQLSRV), so there's an off-chance, you are using an outdated version that does not support setting the ChracterSet, although that is unlikely. Changing `char_set` to UTF-16 is not an option, as SQLSRV only supports UTF-8.

More likely one of the following applies:

- in your php.ini the option `default_charset` is not set to UTF-8
- as you probably are working on a Windows machine, your .php-file is not encoded in UTF-8.

If this does not solve the problem, then your input probably contains one ore more characters, which are not valid UTF-8. In this case try converting your (user) input with `iconv()`.

edit: Regarding @Markus comment: CodeIgniter's [system/database/drivers/sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php) looks like a simple wrapper around the [sqlsrv-commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928321%28v=sql.10%29.aspx), it seems therefore unlikely, that the problem
is caused by CodeIgniter-code.

Comment: That indeed sounds like pain... In other words I'll have to check all my inputs if they contain UTF-16 characters, and if they do convert them to UTF-8 prior submitting to the database? Ouch... I'll try updating my sqlsrv driver and accept this answer once confirmed!

Comment: only converting using iconv as proposed by @Amin_Adha worked. Setting the default_charset makes no difference (I'm not using code igniter btw)

Answer (score 0):

I had this **error:**

> Error Number: IMSSP

An error occurred translating the query string to UTF-16: No hay ninguna asignación en la página de códigos de múltiples bytes de destino para el carácter Unicode. .

And for me workrs with:

```
iconv('','utf-8',$pass);
```

before doing the query on the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but only [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php/%22htmlspecialchars%22) worked for me.

```
$value = htmlspecialchars($input)
```

Comment: You really should not change the user input when storing it into the database.

Answer (score -2):

Try with utf-16 encoding, both in :

```
$config['charset'] = 'utf-16';
```

and

```
$db['local']['char_set'] = 'utf16';
```

And also the db encoding must be set properly as utf-16.

Comment: These settings make me unable to connect to my database. The problem is that there is no way of setting manually the default collation of MSSQL... Not in the same way I can in MySQL at least...