# No rows returned when using codeigniter sqlsrv with arabic words in where clause

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, sqlsrv

I have codeigniter connected to sqlsrv DB i want to use Arabic words in a where clause:

```
$this->db—>get_where(“codes”,array(“name”,”كلمة”);
```

note: sqlsrv driver installed correctly

The problem is that while using Arabic words in to select rows I get 0 rows returned.  I tested in laravel framework where it works but in codeigniter I get 0 rows

Comment: What is the problem that you experience?

Comment: while using arabic words in to select rows i get 0 rows. i tested in laravel framework it works but in codeigniter i get 0 rows :/

Comment: Check out that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178795/how-to-store-multi-byte-characters-in-sql-server-database-using-codeigniter which I think will help you to fix your issue.

Comment: i tried it not works i think the problem in codeigniter sqlsrv driver

Comment: Do you have errors?

Comment: no there is no errors in php and mssql  “debug logs turned on”